# Can't set headers after they are sent in ftp library

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I am using ftp library on npm. I am facing this error

```
_http_outgoing.js:357
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/nomanmaqsood/Documents/netsuite-ftp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:730:10)
```

First time I get proper response from the library on second call my node app crash due to the above error. Here is my code kindly guide me where is the mistake

```
c.on ('ready', function () {
            c.list (function (err, list) {
                if (err) {
                    c.end();
                } else {
                    if (list.length > 0) {
                        c.end(); 
                        return res.status(200).json({data:list});//crash here on 2nd call
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

please help me out

Comment: Looks like you are sending the response before setting the header. Perhaps  seperate res.status(200).json() line into two lines eg. res.status(200), res.json(...);

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't call `res.json` or `res.send` twice on one client http request.

Try

```
c.on ('ready', function () {
    c.list (function (err, list) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.message});

        c.end(); 
        res.status(200).json({data: list || []});
    });
});
```

P.S. I suppose that you use `Express`.

Comment: Yes I am using express, Same error with this code as well

Answer (score 0):

the c was global object, which register itself twice. just make the object local and things works like charm